# Schedule a task to run monthly the second week?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a task that runs the 1st monthly, but I would like it to 
run the second Tuesday of each month.

Is there a way I can schedule this on Coldfusion admin?
Or how can I make this happen?

The task is very simple it just sends a email to certain people monthly.

I have coldfusion 9.

Comment: The only way I've been able to achieve this is to run the task every Tuesday and then within your cfm page check if it's the 2nd Tuesday of the month and run the report then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always set it to trigger every seven days from a tuesday and  place this in the top of the job

The first date of the month that can be a second occurrence is the 8th, the last is the 14th.

```
<cfif dayofweekasstring(dayofweek(now())) is "Tuesday" and day(now()) lte 14 and day(now()) gte 8>
  Abort job.
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use crontime, your cron expression should be something like

`0 0 0 8-14 * 2`

The first 3 zeros are seconds, minutes and hours, so the cron expression above will run on the second tuesday of any month at 0:00:00

See the documentation here: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06

**UPDATE**

Crontime does not support using both day of the month and day of the week in the same expression.

Comment: I don't know if the answer is correct or not, but I upvoted it to get your reputation into triple digits.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: I've got egg on my face. Just tried to create a scheduled task and got the CF said "Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented."

Comment: Documentation link appears to have been moved to http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html